# How would I use a Realm database on Android from Objective-C?

Tags: android, c++, objective-c, android-ndk, realm

We are experimenting with porting our Objective-C code to Android by using the CrystaX NDK. This is an alternate NDK which supports objective-C along with extended C++ functionality. So far, everything looks like it is going to be easy to work with except Realm as it is very language dependent on how you make Database tables. The Objective-C side of Realm already has a compiled iOS library we can't use on Realm and it would obviously be a pain to make all our tables in Java and then bridge them to Objective-C. Is there a solution here?

Comment: This link says Realm is available for Android: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/realm/info

Comment: @RichardCritten - Yes, I know, but it uses Java. Our code is in Objective-C and it would require an extensive bridging layer to use it and use the same source code across all of our platforms

Comment: As far as I see, there are sources for Realm for Objective-C - https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa, so (theoretically) it could be built for Android with CrystaX NDK.

Comment: @DmitryMoskalchuk - I knew that previously the core database technology was closed source, and I thought this was still the case, but now I am not seeing the closed source library. We'll look into this further. Thanks!

Comment: @David quick question - how is the experiment going? Is the port working well with Crystal NDK?

Comment: @RoopeshShenoy - We had some issues along the way and decided for V1 of our software we were going iOS only. After porting is compete, we will test CrystaX again. If we can't make it work, we intend to go strait C++.

Comment: @David thanks for that info. We digged a bit into CrystaX too, but now we're considering C++ directly too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core database of Realm is still closed source, and while you could technically use the same C++ API's the bindings use, I wouldn't recommend it as they are not suited for that use case nor are they documented very well at the moment.

You might be able to use the dynamic API's on both platforms, but you would loose a lot of the type-safety doing so.

Right now I am afraid it would probably be better to wait until we ship a proper C++ API.

Comment: What sort of timeframe are you looking at for the C++ API at this point? We are shipping the product in Q1 2016 and really need to ensure that Realm will be able to be used in the long run and for release.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, you are saying that it might be possible to link the open source Objective-c code to the Android Realm-Core library on Android?

Comment: At the moment, early beta looks possible in Q1 next year, but that can still be subject to change, so I would not build a product strategy around it.

Comment: Regarding linking the Object-C code to the Android Core library, then no, that is really not possible. The reason is that Android cannot execute native cod directly but has to go through a custom JNI layer which uses other method names than Objective-C knows about.

Comment: Once the C++ API Is out, would it theoretically be possible to use the same C++ code interface (from obj-c++) across windows/android/ios/mac? Also, would you guess that the db format would be the same so that you could move to a c++ interface and use the same db that was written by the Obj-C version?